# display image in iframe, image is larger than the iframe. Can I make it fit using HTML?

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to display an image in iframe, image is larger than the iframe. Can I make it fit using HTML ?

Photo is 400 x 200, my iframe is 200x100, Is there an HTML coded iframe that will automatically fit the image to the iframe border?

Comment: 1) why iframe, why not div? 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029422/image-auto-resize-to-fit-div-container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779305/make-responsive-image-fit-parent-container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037566/make-an-image-fit-its-container-by-setting-the-image-height-to-the-containers-he

Comment: No, you can't. Unless you have access to the source code of the file within the iframe, and this way you can set a class to it with a code like `img.some_class { max-width:100% !important;
    max-height:100% !important;
    display:block;}`.
But you can't style elements inside an iframe with CSS placed on the parent document (iframe holder).

Answer (score -1):

use `seamless` attribute in iframe :
`<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" seamless> </iframe>` 
And Css
`iframe img{width:200px;}`
**Note :** The seamless attribute is not supported in IE, Firefox, Opera 12 and earlier versions.

Comment: Yeah, as of this date, it may work except in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari (sarcasm). http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-seamless

Comment: (not that I'm saying OP shouldn't just go with an img tag)

Comment: Not supported in any browsers