# Make Image Link Container Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website running with Bootstrap. I'm trying to get an image to match its container's height ([it's huge right now](https://www.k7dxs.xyz/)). I've seen [make an image fit its container by setting the image height to the containers height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037566/make-an-image-fit-its-container-by-setting-the-image-height-to-the-containers-he) but it's not working. My best guess as to why is because it's inside a link:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">K7DXS</a>-->
```

Here's the image:

```
      <a class-"navbar-brand" class="k7dxslogo" href="/"><img src="/k7dxsblink.gif" class="k7dxslogo" alt="K7DXS" /></a>
```

The rest of the code:

```
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/linux.php">Linux</a></li>
                <li><a href="/radio.php">Ham Radio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/partners.php">Partner Sites</a></li>
        <li><a href="/links.php">External Links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

My relevant style.css:

```
.k7dxslogo {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Why isn't it working, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I do NOT want to set a definite height for anything. To do so would make it so that the site is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Add "img-responsive" class to your HTML img tag.

Set a defined height for navbar-brand

Comment: Added img-responsive, no luck. Why do I need to set a defined height? I just want it to be what Bootstrap makes it.

Comment: Because bootstrap has no rules regarding navbar brand images. If you set your .navbar-brand at 60px (example), and your .navbar-brand img at a defined height and width:auto smaller than 60px; in theory it should work fine

Comment: But how do I get it to match the *navbar's* height?